# What are methods to make Docker work faster when using it for tests?

Tags: docker, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

My ultimate goal is to create a test environment where auxiliary services (microservices, databases, message queues, etc) could be easily provided in clean state for each test.

Currently I achieved somewhat fast operation times by not doing `docker run ...`, `docker rm ...` for each container but instead putting all the mutable data on to a volume and do `docker start ...`, `docker stop ...`, `<remove data from volume>`, `docker start ...`. It is faster, but still not satisfactory in practice - test runs take too long time if the amount of tests is big.

So currently I know only one approach to speed up re-creation of Docker containers:

1. Use a volume with mutable data and clean it up between `start`/`stop` instead of doing full re-creation.

What are other possible approaches?

Comment: Do you have a [mcve] demonstrating a slow setup?  IME it's very unusual to need `docker start` at all, can you leave the containers running instead of stopping and restarting them (or deleting and recreating them)?  Can you arrange a useful subset of the tests to run without Docker at all, and have developers run those as part of their core workflow?

Comment: @DavidMaze, but how to return a service to a "clean" state without restarting?

Comment: Stopping and starting a container leaves the container filesystem in place, so with something stateful like a database it'd still have the old state.  IME it's usually fine to use the same database across an entire integration-test sequence, even if your test setup needs to create and delete objects along the way.

Comment: @DavidMaze, you can clean the state in between of these commands. I made a mistake in the text and didn't reflect that.